# My Azure DNS won't propagate

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I've followed the guide here (https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/?fb=en-US).

It states how to set up a domain.

Now, my web-app works when going to http://fablelane.com. This app makes a redirect to http://www.fablelane.com, which then returns a 404 (the redirect is normal, and is part of my URL rewriting rules, proving that the http://fablelane.com URL works).

If I go to http://fablelane.azurewebsites.net/, the entire website loads without issues. But here, it doesn't make the redirect either.

Whenever I try to add the domain in Azure, I get the exclamation mark indicating that something is wrong.

[image]

If I hover over the exclamation mark, the following error is displayed.

> The DNS record for 'www.fablelane.com' that points to 'fablelane.azurewebsites.net' could not be located. If you want to configure an A record, you must first create a CNAME record with your DNS provider for 'awverify.www.fablelane.com' that points to 'awverify.fablelane.azurewebsites.net'. First allow the resource record to propagate, and then create the A record.

Finally, here are my DNS settings from my control panel.

[image]

I have waited more than 24 hours for the DNS to propagate, and still my site returns a 404. The instance is a dedicated instance.

**Edit**

I have now removed the URL rewriting rule, so that you can go to http://fablelane.com directly, which works. http://www.fablelane.com still doesn't work though, which is my main problem.

Comment: DNS doesn't propagate. Neither its documentation does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! After 30 hours of hard working, I tried removing the `*.fablelane.com` A-record, and the `www.fablelane.com` A-record. I had suspected that the order of the DNS records might have influenced the result.

Now it works.

Comment: That's not how DNS works, but there no such thing as A-record propagation either...